# JQuery: How to run background music in website?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am searching for a plugin or code using which I'll be able to run background music when my website will open. This type of functionality normally found in flash website, where background, but I want to make it using jquery in my website,

Please provide any plugin or code link, which will help me in this issue.

Thanks

Comment: Please could you give us a list of all the websites you are going to be adding music to, so we can avoid them forever.

Comment: Hey cmon guys, he may not have a choice :)

Comment: @nickf, I am not a big fan of background-music on site, but my client wants it. Even I explained him, that it will slow down the site and also will disturb the user but he says no issues just implement it. So its totally a client requirement not mine.

Comment: You might want to try steering him toward a user-initiated music option. This really is the kind of thing that drives users away -- fast. If this site's for a 13-year-old girl on MySpace who wants dancing pink ponies, maybe it doesn't matter. But this is deadly on a commercial site. Oh, and it's soooo 1995! Good luck!

Comment: @Peter, I understand all the issues, but client doesn't. Most of the time, clients try to be over smart. So for now I must have to implement this option, but may be after using it he'll realize the problem better.

Comment: http://www.seomoz.org/blog/how-to-convince-a-client-their-site-doesnt-need-music and http://doodlekit.com/blog/entry/37742/why-you-should-avoid-background-music-on-your-website but indeed, sometimes it's not that easy to convince all of them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I use the [JPlayer](http://www.jplayer.org/) plugin. It has methods you can call to run audio at any time and without a player.

Comment: This is cool and works for me. I choose this because I'm already using JQuery library in ma website. :D Thanks

Comment: jPlayer is now found at: http://www.jplayer.org/

Answer (score 8):

This is a perfectly good and acceptable question.

If you site consists of more than one page - it's not Flash nor full Ajax (like Gmail) - you have to make sure the player stays on a frame that does not change so that your music does not stop when you click a link.

```
 ---------------------
|    site content     |
|                     |
|---------------------
|  invisible frame    |
 ---------------------
```

This will also mean that a problem can arise with searching bots that may point directly into a frame of your site - skipping the index and thus disabling music. If that is not the case you should be fine.

You can then use a sound library [SoundManager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/), like @VoxPelli pointed out, to control your javascript. Do notice that the site @VoxPelli mentions is a great example of a site with music! However when you click on *explore* the music breaks as the user is directed to a new page. The only way to overcome this is with frames.

Hope it helps!

Comment: +1 Interesting workaround for page browsing.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to look into the [HTML 5 `<audio>` tag](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/), although if you want IE support you'll ultimately have to fall back to a plugin like Flash or Quicktime.

Comment: This is probably the easiest way to get sound on your site.

Comment: +1, why should I mess around with jQuery/Javascript, when you simply need HTM?!. With MP3 it works IE9+, Chrome4+, FF3.5+, and for Safari 5.1.7 you need to convert audio file in .OGG Audio browsers' support here: http://caniuse.com/audio

Answer (score 2):

I think the way to go is the [SoundManager](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/) library - I've used it for a similar purpose where a client demanded to have background music.

It's also used by sites like [CitySounds.fm](http://citysounds.fm/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this [(pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/dKkvDUgx):

```
<!-- START SOUND CODE V3.15  -->
<center>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
// PLAYER VARIABLES

var mp3snd = "/TehSteve/bgmusic1.mp3";
var bkcolor = "000000";

if ( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf( "msie" ) != -1 ) {
document.write('<bgsound src="'+mp3snd+'" loop="1">');
}
else if ( navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf( "firefox" ) != -1 ) {
document.write('<object data="'+mp3snd+'" type="application/x-mplayer2" width="0" height="0">');
document.write('<param name="filename" value="'+mp3snd+'">');
document.write('<param name="autostart" value="1">');
document.write('</object>');
}
else {
document.write('<audio src="'+mp3snd+'" autoplay="autoplay">');
document.write('<object data="'+mp3snd+'" type="application/x-mplayer2" width="0" height="0">');
document.write('<param name="filename" value="'+mp3snd+'">');
document.write('<param name="autostart" value="1">');
document.write('<embed height="2" width="2" src="'+mp3snd+'" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/" type="video/quicktime" controller="false" controls="false" autoplay="true" autostart="true" loop="false" bgcolor="#'+bkcolor+'"><br>');
document.write('</embed></object>');
document.write('</audio>');
}
//-->
</script>
<br>
</center>
<!-- END SOUND CODE V3.15 -->
```

Comment: Browser detection is evil!

Answer (score 0):

The only cross-browser, OS-independent way you can do this horrible thing is to use an invisible flash applet that exposes an API you can control via Javascript. Sadly, I don't know how to make one and I can't find an invisible player anywhere so I guess my answer isn't very useful. Oh well.