# How to mute background music in html page

Tags: html, background-music

As per clients requirement, i have added a background music to webpage. I have set the music in loop mode to play it continuous. I have used <BGSOUND> tag to play the audio. The problem here is how to implement mute button so that client can mute the playing sound. I know nowadays its a bad idea to play automatic background music, but its the clients requirement. The page is simple static html.

Do anybody have the idea how to provide button to mute background sound?

Thanks for sharing your time.

Comment: **Use jquery** This question has already been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1665236/jquery-how-to-run-background-music-in-website)

Comment: It is recommended not to put music in the first place, Without the user's desire

Comment: "not recommended" sounds like browsers could have problems playing sound/music, which is not-right...

after all, it is the mute button he's looking for ;-)

Comment: Thanks Harsha, but i dont want any control, just simple BGSOUND.

Comment: @SpliFF - he he he he, me too but client is client, although i have explained him the drawbacks. but ah....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your BGSOUND has it's id attribute set, then it should be as simple as setting
the src attribute to blank :

> document.all["bgsound_id"].src="";

Comment: where do you put the 'document.all["bgsound_id"].src="";' code?